# attempt to invoke method on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am writing an android app and I am getting this error. I commented almost every part of my code and the only parts that remained un-commented are the following :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int digi=0;
public PointCalculator pointCalculator;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    digi = pointCalculator.digicalculator();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), digi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

and the PointCalculator:

```
  public  int digicalculator()
{
    int digipoints=0;
    digipoints = digipoints + 30;
    return digipoints;
}
```

and this is logcat :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.neshat.test/com.example.neshat.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.neshat.test.PointCalculator.digicalculator()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.neshat.test.PointCalculator.digicalculator()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.neshat.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I cannot understand what causes the problem.

Comment: Where are you assigning pointCalculator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not allocated memory to the pointCalculator object :

```
pointCalculator = new PointCalculator();
digi = pointCalculator.digicalculator();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your `PointCalculator` first.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int digi=0;
public PointCalculator pointCalculator = new PointCalculator(); //<--- Initialized
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    digi = pointCalculator.digicalculator();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), digi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialised your PointCalculator.

```
public PointCalculator pointCalculator;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pointCalculator = new PointCalculator(); // Here it's initialised 
    digi = pointCalculator.digicalculator();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), digi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using object **`PointCalculator`**  without initializing it, so that is your concern. Try to init it in onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pointCalculator = new PointCalculator(); //init
    digi = pointCalculator.digicalculator();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), digi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```